# Why does this for-loop only run once?

Tags: java

The goal of my code: To be able to write a program where I can enter in any number int as a command-line argument and displays how many digits in the integer number are 7s.

My problem is that I don't understand why my code only runs through the for-loop once. I inserted the system.out.println(sevens); to see how many times this loop works when I compile with a random number like 456789.

I could only think of a for-loop to use for this one and fixed some simple mistakes in the beginning. I also checked my brackets

```
public class TestingSevens {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sevens = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (sevens%10 == 7) {
                count += 1;
            }
            sevens = sevens/10;
            System.out.println(sevens);
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

The result of inputting a number like 456789 is "45678" for the first print and the second print is "0." I know the number for some reason only runs through the loop once since it cuts off the last number before jumping out of the loop to print the count...any advice?

Comment: What’s the value for args.length?

Comment: *"when I compile with a random number like 456789"* First, you don't *compile* with that number, you *run* with that as an argument, and it is only **one** argument, a string of length 6, so `args.length` is 1 and the loop only iterates once.

Comment: This is a well-written question. There's a minimal set of code that we can run, the OP explains what they're inputting and the incorrect result they're seeing, and they've attempted to debug it themselves. Don't downvote just because it's from a beginner.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your time! I tried some of your advice while also limiting myself on what I can use due to my professor's requirements. The result is changing one line to (int i = 0; i < sevens; i++) from a deleted comment...Also thanks John for the little support, I am very new so I appreciate the words :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to iterate over each digit of `sevens`. Since `sevens` initialized from `args[0]`, the loop limit should match and look at `args[0].length()` rather than `args.length`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < args[0].length(); i++)
```

An alternate way to write the loop is to iterate until `sevens` reaches 0. That lines up better with the loop body; both use the same variable.

```
while (sevens > 0) {
    if (sevens%10 == 7) {
        count += 1;
    }
    sevens /= 10;
    System.out.println(sevens);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has logic errors, so to check if the iterated number is number 7 you need to turn the number into a string and check if the character is the desired character using: `numberString.charAt(index)`

Below is the corrected code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sevens = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String numberString = String.valueOf(sevens);
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberString.length(); i++) {
        char c = numberString.charAt(i);        

        if (c == '7') {
            count += 1;
        }

        System.out.println("Input number: " + sevens);
    }
    System.out.println("Count of 7 numbers: " + count);
}
```